# How to handle multiple NuGet pushes from DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Our team is a .NET team that produces multiple NuGet packages in 2 different Azure Git repos. These repos are protected by a policy preventing direct pushes to master; a PR needs to be peer reviewed to allow the changes to occur. Once a PR is completed an Azure Release pipeline can be manually fired for each package to update it.
This is all good, however we have packages dependent on other packages in the same repos (via NuGet, not project references) and it becomes a cascade of PR > Release > Update project reference(s) > PR > Release etc - up to 10 times depending which package has had code updates.
Surely we're not the only team with this problem, and surely there's a better way? I can't seem to find a solution out there unless we reference the packages as "*" and I'm not even sure if that will work.

Comment: Why do projects in the same repo use packages, and not ProjectReference?  If they're "normal" class libraries, then it will work just the same if you use ProjectReference. When you pack the project, NuGet will determine the project's version, and then add it as a nuget dependency of that version, just the same as a package reference becomes a dependency.

Comment: Mostly because that involves making sure developers synchronise project version (manually editing the version field of the csproj file) and NuGet version (which comes from a pipeline after CI)